# properties file in parent project

Tags: maven

When I build a sub project I am trying to reference a properties file in the parent project.

**POM from sub project**

```
...
<parent>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>${parent.version}</version>
</parent>
...
```

The file is located in /parent/testproperties/dev.

**POM from parent project**

```
...
<properties>
    <test.properties>${project.build.directory}/../../testproperties/dev/test.properties</test.properties>
    <maven-antrun-plugin-phase>none</maven-antrun-plugin-phase>
</properties>
...
```

Maven can't find the file.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What is wrong? What isn't found? Does `${project.build.directory}/../../testproperties/dev/` exists?

Comment: Yes, ${project.build.directory}/../../testproperties/dev/ exists.  It gets interpreted as C:/code/PropertiesFiltering/testproperties/dev/test.properties  The test.properties file exists in that location.  When building from the submodule Maven does not recognize that the file is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this did not work is the required file is not in the classpath of the submodule.  The submodule does not inherit the parent module classpath.  Got it to work by having the parent module copy the required file into the submodules' classpaths.